# Storing CURL response in MySQL database results in a question mark at the beginning of the column

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter, curl, codeigniter-3

I'm calling an API using cURL that returns a UTF-8 XML string. When I store that in my MySQL database (as a longtext) the beginning of the string is prepended by a plaintext question mark.

As found on another StackOverflow question, I tried setting my cURL encoding to UTF-8 which unfortunately didn't help. Interestingly, if I just output the results of `curl_exec()` to the browser the question isn't there.

It's worth noting that while I'm using CodeIgniter 3 for the database insert, I'm not using CI's cURL library (or any other).

Any suggestions?

Comment: Post the code where you're doing the request and inserting the data

Answer (score 0):

Are you decoding the xml on receipt? try using [simplexml_load_string()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.simplexml-load-string.php)

```
$xml = simplexml_load_string($your_string);
print_r($xml);
```